# Multiple conditions in if statement shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement, conditional-statements, account

I would like to know whether it is possible to have more than two statements in an `if` statement when you are writing a shell script?

```
username1="BOSS1"
username2="BOSS2"
password1="1234"
password2="4321"

if(($username == $username1)) && (($password == password1)) || 
  (($username == $username2)) && (($password == password2)) ; then
```

This does NOT work. But is there a way to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

if using `/bin/sh` you can use:

```
if [ <condition> ] && [ <condition> ]; then
    ...
fi
```

if using `/bin/bash` you can use:

```
if [[ <condition> && <condition> ]]; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 13):

You are trying to compare strings inside an arithmetic command (`((...))`). Use `[[` instead.

```
if [[ $username == "$username1" && $password == "$password1" ]] ||
   [[ $username == "$username2" && $password == "$password2" ]]; then
```

Note that I've reduced this to two separate tests joined by `||`, with the `&&` moved inside the tests. This is because the shell operators `&&` and `||` have equal precedence and are simply evaluated from left to right. As a result, it's not generally true that `a && b || c && d` is equivalent to the intended `( a && b ) || ( c && d )`.

Comment: Also be careful about whitespace. All those spaces need to be there! It must be `if [[ $username` and not `if[[$username`. Correct whitespace is critical in shell scripts, unlike most other programming languages.